# Poor predictions

Tags: tensorflow

I have some input data (11 real values) and I need to do regression of 3 output values. I have a big training set with data. When I train the model, the RMSE is roughly at 45, which I consider to be very good.

I have some problems with my model when it comes to do predictions with new data. It seems that the model is not performing well when exposed to new data. Here is the code:

```
    normalizer = preprocessing.Normalization()
    normalizer.adapt(x_train)
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      normalizer,
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=self._root_mean_squared_error)
    es_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, epochs=100, batch_size=50, shuffle=True, callbacks=[es_callback])
```

I have some questions:

- Do you see something wrong with how I create the model?
- I assume that the normalizer layer acts as a normalizer for input queries, is that right? Meaning, I do not normalize the input data when I query the neural network.

Comment: Probably increase patience in early stopping (while restoring "best weights"), probably use callback to save model progress (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint). You may also increase epochs quite a lot. Is there a reason for your dense layers having all 50 hidden units?

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for your feedback. There is no reason for 50 hidden units, do you reckon this is too high?

Comment: Often you see architectures, where the units in the dense layers are decreased, e.g. first layer 64, second layer 32, third layer 8...  Did you check alternative models (e.g. random forest). Maybe NN overengineers the problem...

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look. Is my assumption about the normalizer layer true? That that's the way to go and that queries made to the network doesn't need to be normalized henceforth?

Comment: I never used it, I use sklearn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html), but it looks okay. Just as a reminder: you need to make sure that test data (or any "new" data) is scaled by the mean, sd that comes from the train data. This is why I use sklearn since you can easily store (save) the scaler object to apply it to "new" data.